# Running macro present in one excel file from another excel file

Tags: excel, vba, macos, excel-formula

I am writing a macro in one of the excel files. I want to run that from another excel sheet.

My code:

```
Sub Full_Automation()
    Dim All_Submitted_Dates As Variant
    Dim All_WorkWeek As Variant
    Dim dctUnique_WorkWeek As Dictionary
    Dim DateCounter As Long
    Dim WorkWeekCounter As Long

    Sheet1.Activate
    Set dctUnique_WorkWeek = New Dictionary

With Sheet1
    All_Submitted_Dates = Application.Transpose(.Range(.Range("K2"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp)))
End With

    WorkWeekCounter = 1

For DateCounter = 1 To UBound(All_Submitted_Dates)
    If Not dctUnique_WorkWeek.Exists("WW" & WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(All_Submitted_Dates(DateCounter))) Then
        dctUnique_WorkWeek.Add Key:="WW" & WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(All_Submitted_Dates(DateCounter)), Item:=1
    Else
        dctUnique_WorkWeek("WW" & WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(All_Submitted_Dates(DateCounter))) = dctUnique_WorkWeek("WW" & WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(All_Submitted_Dates(DateCounter))) + 1
    End If
Next DateCounter

    Worksheets.Add after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Worksheets(3).Activate


    Dim rowCounter As Long
    Dim varKey As Variant

    rowCounter = 2


    For Each varKey In dctUnique_WorkWeek.Keys()
        Range("A" & rowCounter).Value = varKey
        Range("D" & rowCounter).Value = dctUnique_WorkWeek(varKey)

        If rowCounter = 2 Then
            Range("C" & rowCounter).Formula = "=B" & rowCounter
            Range("E" & rowCounter).Formula = "=D" & rowCounter
        Else
            Range("C" & rowCounter).Formula = "=C" & (rowCounter - 1) & "+B" & rowCounter
            Range("E" & rowCounter).Formula = "=E" & (rowCounter - 1) & "+D" & rowCounter
        End If
        rowCounter = rowCounter + 1
    Next

End Sub
```

When I tried to debug the code line by line, I got to know that whenever I execute the line `Sheet1.Activate` it going to the original excel file where my macro is present. 
How will I refer to the first worksheet of another workbook?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31697629/reference-an-excel-sheet-from-another-workbook-without-copying-the-sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Sheets` collection is a property of the `Workbook` object (observe that the `Sheets` collection is more inclusive than the `worksheets` collection because not all `Sheets` are `Worksheets`). The default workbook is the `ActiveWorkbook` and this will be addressed if you don't specify anything else.

You can assign a workbook to a variable declared as `Workbook`.

```
Dim Wb As Workbook
Set Wb = ThisWorkbook
or 
Set Wb = ActiveWorkbook
or
Set Wb = Workbooks.Open ([File name])
or
Set Wb = Workbooks.Add ([Template])
```

You can then address any sheet in the designated workbook.

```
Debug.Print Wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value
```

Answer (score 1):

Early binding can load the dictionary object within the initial declaration.

```
Set dctUnique_WorkWeek = New Dictionary
```

This creates a 1-D array but you start the increment in the For ... Next at 1, not zero. Probably better to simply use a 2-D array. In fact, I've it expedient to always use LBound to UBound for a For ... Next involving an array.

```
With Sheet1
    All_Submitted_Dates = Application.Transpose(.Range(.Range("K2"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp)))
End With
```

The codename Sheet1 is going to refer to the Sheet1 within the workbook containing the VBA project. Use the worksheet's name and provide an explicit parent workbook if external.

```
Sheet1.Activate
```

In fact, there is no need to .Activate a worksheet to reference it as long as an explicitly referenced parent workbook is provided.

```
dctUnique_WorkWeek("WW" & WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(All_Submitted_Dates(DateCounter))) = dctUnique_WorkWeek("WW" & WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(All_Submitted_Dates(DateCounter))) + 1
```

a) VBA's Format uses the *ww* format mask to retrieve the same number as WorksheetFunction.WeekNum. b) There is a shorthand 'countif in a dictionary' that bypasses the dictionary's Exists method.

*WorkWeekCounter* doesn't appear to be used beyond being declared and assigned a value of 1.

```
WorkWeekCounter = 1
```

You can write all of the keys and items at once. The formulas will require 2 steps due to the different formulas.

```
For Each varKey In dctUnique_WorkWeek.Keys()
```

Your formulas seem to reference column B yet no values are put into column B on the new worksheet.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Full_Automation()

    Dim All_Submitted_Dates As Variant, dctUnique_WorkWeek As New Dictionary
    Dim dc As Long

    With ActiveWorkbook  'better as With Workbooks("Book1.xlsx")

        With .Worksheets("Sheet1")
            All_Submitted_Dates = .Range(.Cells(2, "K"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp)).Value2
        End With

        For dc = LBound(All_Submitted_Dates, 1) To UBound(All_Submitted_Dates, 1)
            dctUnique_WorkWeek.Item("WW" & Right(Format(All_Submitted_Dates(dc, 1), "\0ww"), 2)) = _
                dctUnique_WorkWeek.Item("WW" & Right(Format(All_Submitted_Dates(dc, 1), "\0ww"), 2)) + 1
        Next dc

        Worksheets.Add After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)

        With .Sheets(.Sheets.Count)

            'name = "give the new worksheet a name"

            .Cells(2, "A").Resize(dctUnique_WorkWeek.Count, 1) = Application.Transpose(dctUnique_WorkWeek.keys)
            .Cells(2, "D").Resize(dctUnique_WorkWeek.Count, 1) = Application.Transpose(dctUnique_WorkWeek.items)

            'optionally sort the weeks
            With .Cells(2, "A").Resize(dctUnique_WorkWeek.Count, 4)
                .Sort key1:=.Cells(1), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
            End With

            .Cells(2, "C").Formula = "=B2"
            .Cells(2, "E").Formula = "=D2"

            .Range(.Cells(3, "C"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2)).Formula = "=C2+B3"
            .Range(.Cells(3, "E"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 4)).Formula = "=E2+D3"

        End With

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It really helped me optimize my code.