# Modify embedded Excel workbook in another Excel workbook VBA

Tags: excel, vba, createoleobject

I have an Excel workbook in which I have embedded another Excel workbook. I am able to open it with VBA, but I have no idea how to refer and edit some cells in embedded workbook. Any idea how to do that? Thanks a lot in advance.

```
Sub openembeddedXL2()

Sheets("sheet1").OLEObjects("SalesFile").Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: `Workbooks("SalesFile").Sheets(` etc. would work to reference to the open workbook.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference an excel sheet from another workbook without copying the sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31697629/reference-an-excel-sheet-from-another-workbook-without-copying-the-sheet)

Comment: "SalesFile" is not the name of the Workbook, but the name of the object, so I dont think I can reference it like that.

Comment: It wasn't as straightforward as I assumed it to be, but after some rigorous testing I figured it out for you as per my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as a workbook is open you can directly refer to it by its name.

`Workbooks("workbook name")` etc.

Since you open the workbook with `Sheets("sheet1").OLEObjects("SalesFile").Activate` the workbook related to the object will then be opened as a file called "Worksheet in *your current workbook*". You can therefore use:

```
Dim wb as workbook
Sheets("sheet1").OLEObjects("SalesFile").Activate
set wb = Workbooks("Worksheet in " & ThisWorkbook.Name)
Thisworkbook.sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").value = wb.sheets("Sheet1").range("A1").Value 'etc. etc.
wb.Close
```

`Thisworkbook` is a handy tool here, as it will always refer to the workbook the macro is in, despite which workbook is currently active.